# О правильности использования притяжательных местоимений «наши», «наше» при цитировании

Tags: местоимения, цитирование, косвенная

В предложениях с косвенной речью в придаточной части употребляются только местоимения третьего лица. Но допустимо ли в косвенной речи, которая закавычена, использовать местоимения первого лица?

Например, в СМИ пишут:

> Глава Чечни, говоря о ситуации на Украине, назвал ее угрозой для России, отметив, что переговоры для достижения мирного решения конфликта — это хорошо, однако в настоящее время из-за военных действий умирают «наши братья, наши близкие и друзья», на что мало кто обращает должное внимание.

Если же нельзя так писать, то как можно будет заменить "наши", если нет уверенности в том, кто такие "наши"?

С другой стороны, в правилах (http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/164-znapr) приводится такая цитата:

*Справедливо сказал Гоголь, что «в Пушкине, как будто в лексиконе, заключилось все богатство, гибкость и сила нашего языка».
Белинский*

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос некорректен. В кавычках приводятся точные слова цитируемого источника, без изменений (если они не отмечены, как требуют правила). О "можно" или "нельзя" тут вообще говорить нет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Правило оформления прямой речи**: При замене прямой речи косвенной личные и притяжательные местоимения, а также личные формы глаголов передаются от лица автора, рассказчика, а **не от лица того**, чья речь передаётся.
2. *Глава Чечни, говоря о ситуации на Украине, назвал ее угрозой для России, отметив, что переговоры для достижения мирного решения конфликта — это хорошо, однако в настоящее время из-за военных действий умирают «**наши братья, наши близкие и друзья**», на что мало кто обращает должное внимание.*

Здесь **неправильно** использовано местоимение "наши", так как это местоимение относится к тому лицу, которое цитируется (то есть к главе Чечни).

3. *Справедливо сказал Гоголь, что «**в Пушкине, как будто в лексиконе, заключилось все богатство, гибкость и сила нашего языка***». Белинский.

В данном случае местоимение наше относится **ко всем указанным лицам** (к Гоголю и Пушкину). Поэтому фраза выглядит корректно.

**В качестве приложения**

[https://syntax.academic.ru/242/правила_перестройки_прямой_речи_в_косвенную](https://syntax.academic.ru/242/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E)

1. форма 1-го лица глагола заменяется на 3-е лицо;
2. личные местоимения **1-го, 2-го лица, притяжательные мой, твой** заменяются местоимениями 3-го лица или употребляется имя существительное;

В приведенном предложении местоимение "наши" забыли заменить...  Поэтому приблизительно правильное (для журналистов) предложение при проведении грамматического анализа таковым считать нежелательно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134593/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).